# test_ssl.py and test_urllib2.py tests are failing in python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

test_ssl.py

```
root@yasir:/home/yasir/PYTHON/python2.7-2.7.6/Lib/test# python  python test_ssl.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_ssl.py", line 7, in <module>
      from test.script_helper import assert_python_ok
ImportError: No module named script_helper
```

test_urllib2.py

```
root@yasir:/home/yasir/PYTHON/python2.7-2.7.6/Lib/test# python test_urllib2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test_urllib2.py", line 3, in <module>
     from test import test_urllib
ImportError: cannot import name test_urllib
```

I'm not able to understand which module is missing so facing this error

Comment: cd up one directory and use `python -m test test_ssl`, you're invoking them in a way that's not designed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tests failed due to missing python module libpython2.7-testsuite